# Matching an empty path only in a Chrome Extension match pattern

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I ONLY want to match

```
*://www.foo.com
```

with either no querystring like above, or any querystring:

```
*://www.foo.com/?*
```

Problem is, how do I match the first pattern above? My guess is I have to just match all paths then exclude all paths, then include the second pattern above.

Any better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried these match patterns? I believe they should work as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your patterns are almost correct. The path name is **required**. Even when the omnibar shows `www.foo.com`, then the path is `/`.

```
*://www.foo.com/
*://www.foo.com/?*
```

Note: the last pattern matches `/?test` but not `/index?test`.
For more information, see [Match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Comment: It looks like a call to `chrome.tabs.query()` does not support the use if `?*` in order to match all tabs with non-empty path in the URL. When passing `{ url: "https://*/?*" }` to the  function call it returns empty array.

Comment: @LeoY `/?` does not match all tabs with non-empty paths. It matches tabs with an empty path AND a query string (`?` is the delimiter that marks the start of a query string). To match all URLs with an empty patch, you'll need to match `/`, `/?*` and `/#*`. Note that in order to get any results, your extension needs to have the `"tabs"` permission, otherwise the array will be empty.